# How to get html with absolute css path in a ajax call response using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have two applications A and B respectively. I am calling application B from A using jquery.$post() and getting response html back from B. This html loads without the css because it has the css files with href pointing to B application's path. Is there any way html can be sent to A from B by adding absolute path to css href using jQuery? So instead of getting something like this in the response HTML

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"`>

Can i get it with absolute path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://<B's server 
 name>/<path to css location in B>/theme.css">
```

in the html sent to A?

Any other better solution is much appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing that does this automatically. You should probably change the documents to use absolute paths in their URLs if this is a general need.

Comment: What about using a symlink on the server?  Then you could request the same file, in the same way, using two different paths.

Comment: If your response html has <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://<B's server 
 name>/<path to css location in B>/theme.css"> in this format itself with absolute path, I don't think there would be problem in loading css then. href works with absolute paths too.